# StackOverflowError during recursive calls to find closest empty index in 2D array

Tags: java

I am trying to use a recursive approach to figure out the closest empty element in my 2D array if the input index already has an element. For example, I call my method `tryPlant(int X, int Y)` to put a symbol in my 2D (32x32) array:

1. ecoArray[X][Y] == "." (empty) then fill it with "~"
2. If there is an element besides ".", then recursively find the next empty spot in the same row first, then column.

The code for the method is:

```
public void tryPlant(int X, int Y){
    if (this.ecoArray[X][Y] == ".") {
        this.ecoArray[X][Y] = "~";
    }else{
        if((Y - 1) >= 0) {
            tryPlant(X, Y - 1);
        }
        else if((Y + 1) <= 32){
            tryPlant(X, Y + 1);
        }else if((X - 1) >= 0 ) {
            tryPlant(X - 1, Y);
        }else if((X + 1) <= 32){
            tryPlant(X + 1, Y);
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the method in another class like this:

```
Plant p1;

private void initPlants(){
        int size = p1.initPop;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int randX = randGen();
            int randY = randGen();
            Plant plant = new Plant(randX, randY, this.ecoArray);
        }
    }
```

The `randGen()` method returns a random integer between 0-31.

Sometimes the random generator gives me indexes such that they do not collide with other objects. An example of this (the `|` are obstacles):

[image: Planting trees]

I want to know why I get a stackoverflow error and what I can do to fix it. If you need any other portions of my code, please ask. I am pretty new to Java.

**Edit**

```
public static int left = 0;
public static int right = 0;

   public void tryPlant(int X, int Y){
        if (this.ecoArray[X][Y] == ".") {
            this.ecoArray[X][Y] = "~";
        }else{

            if((Y - 1) >= 0) {
                this.left++;
                tryPlant(X, Y - 1);
            }
            else if((Y + this.left + 1) <= 32){
                tryPlant(X, Y + this.left + 1);
                this.left = 0;
            }else if((X - 1) >= 0 ) {
                this.right++;
                tryPlant(X - 1, Y);
            }else if((X + this.right + 1) <= 32){
                tryPlant(X + + this.right + 1, Y);
                this.right = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your function is wrong. Imagine for example that you start with X = 0, Y = 1, and both (0,0), and (0,1) cells are occupied. First you move to (0,0). Next iteration takes you back to (0,1), and the situation repeats itself indefinitely.
Each recursive call creates an entry on stack, and eventually it overflows, that's why you get the error. 
You need to work on your algorithm, it does not work at all as it is.

Comment: Oh shoot, you are right. I was thinking of the boundary conditions when I was setting that method up. I will keep thinking about it and get back to you.

Comment: I tried to fix the state you are mentioned with two static integers. It may not be the best way, so please tell me if it the problem is bigger than that.

Comment: Well, I am not sure this is the only problem (probably, not), but, at the very least, your approach seems to also need "up" and "down" in addition to "left", and "right", no?
Also, considering the same case I mentioned before, I don't see how your solution helps: you start at (0,1), move to (0,0), jump back to (0,2) (suppose, it's occupied too), move to (0,1) ... start over.
Why are you set on doing this recursively? It may not be the most intuitive approach to this problem.

Comment: Up and down is handled by changing the X (column) value. I will try to think of a better method to move my plants.

Comment: Edit: This method is sufficient for a moving animal.

Comment: "Up and down is handled by X value": yes, the same way as "right and left is handled by changing the Y value". If you feel that you need the variables for the latter, you should need them for the former as well, the situation is symmetrical.

Comment: I try to understand what you want in output... Is it a path from left to right descending when an obstacle is detected ?

Comment: The path checks left, right, then up, down. If there is an obstacle then it does not go towards it. It looks for the empty path. I think I need to rethink my approach to this. What would be a good way to go about this?

Comment: @mdislam what exactly is the goal? Are you looking for a free cell, that is the *closest* to the current one?

Comment: Where do you start searching and where to you want to go ? That's the question.

Comment: For the initial spawn, the plants are placed based on the Math.random() library which provides an index 0-31. If there is an obstacle, then the closest cell is located. When I want to grow the plant population, I try to grow the plants near each other (which makes logical sense) as long as there is no obstacle (the function will find the nearest location). I store the X, Y location of each plant so I can grow them in the cell later. If you need more clarification, please let me know.

Answer (score -2):

Approximately what happens is: Each time a function is called it is stored in a memory stack. When the function return, what was stored is cleared. But, if you call too many functions, you fullfil the memory and a stackoverflow error is sent.

You get a stackoverflow error because somewhere you have a loop in your algorithm. That cause too many call to `tryPlant()`.

- First, when you find a way where you already pass, return. (where `char == '~'`)
- Second, where there is an obstacle, return. (where `char == '|'`)
- Third, you don't try all directions:

  ```
      if ((Y - 1) >= 0) {
          this.left++;
          tryPlant(X, Y - 1);
      } else if ((Y + this.left + 1) <= 32){
          tryPlant(X, Y + this.left + 1);
          this.left = 0;
      } else if ((X - 1) >= 0 ) {
          this.right++;
          tryPlant(X - 1, Y);
      } else if ((X + this.right + 1) <= 32){
          tryPlant(X + + this.right + 1, Y);
          this.right = 0;
      }
  ```

I tried this and it seems to work:

```
public class Test {

    private char[][] ecoArray;

    public Test() {
        String[] stringArray = new String[] {
        "||.|.||..|..||.|.||||||||..||.||",
        "||||....||..|||..||....|.||..|||",
        "||||||...|.|||...||.|..||..||||.",
        "||...||.|.|||.||||.|||||.|...||.",
        "|.|....|.|||||||||..||.|.|.||...",
        "..|||.||||...|..||.||..|..||||.|",
        "..|.||||||..||.||||..|||.|.|...|",
        "|||||.||.|||...||...||..||.|||..",
        "||||.|..||||||..|.|||...||.||.|.",
        "|||.|||||.|||||.||||.|....||||||",
        "||...||||||.|.|||||||||||.|.|.||",
        "|.|.||||||||.||||....|.||||.||||",
        "||..||.||||.|..||.|||..||.|.||||",
        "..||..|..||.|.|||..|||..|||||.|.",
        "||||.|.||.||||.|||||..|||.|.....",
        "..|.|.|||..|||..||.||||.|||.|..|",
        "||||.|..|||||||.|||||.||.|.|....",
        "..|...||...|||||.|...|..|...|||.",
        "..|||||||..||...||||||..|..|||||",
        "||||..||.|.|||||.||||.|||||.||..",
        "|||||.||||.|....||||....||.||...",
        "||..||.|||||.||||||..||..|....||",
        "|.||||.||..|...|.|..|||.|.|||.||",
        "...||||.|..|||.|||..|.||...|.|||",
        ".||||.|..|.|..||..||..||..||||||",
        "|||.|||..|||..||||.||||.|.||.|||",
        "|||||.||...|.|.|.||...|||..|.|||",
        ".||||.|.|.|||...|||.|||.....||||",
        "|||.|||.|.|...||.|....||||.|.|||",
        ".||||||.|||||||...||..|||.||||.|",
        "||||.|||||.|.||.||||..|.|||.||||",
        "|.|.||||....|.||||||||.|||||.|.|"
        };

        this.ecoArray = new char[32][32];
        int index = 0;
        for (String s : stringArray) {
            this.ecoArray[index] = s.toCharArray(); 
            ++index;
        }
    }

    public void tryPlant(int X, int Y){
        if (this.ecoArray[X][Y] == '~' || this.ecoArray[X][Y] == '|') {
            return;
        }
        if (this.ecoArray[X][Y] == '.') {
            this.ecoArray[X][Y] = '~';

            if ((Y - 1) >= 0) {
                tryPlant(X, Y - 1);
            } 
            if((Y + 1) < 32){
                tryPlant(X, Y + 1);
            }
            if((X - 1) >= 0 ) {
                tryPlant(X - 1, Y);
            }
            if((X + 1) < 32){
                tryPlant(X + 1, Y);
            }
        }
    }

    private void displayInConsole() {
        for (char[] cl : this.ecoArray) {
            System.out.println(cl);
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 32; y++) {
                Test t = new Test();
                t.tryPlant(x, y);
                System.out.println("After tryPlant('" + x + "','" + y + "'): ");
                t.displayInConsole();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Is it doing what you need ? I don't really understand where you want to start and where you want to stop...

The result is too big sorry...

Comment: Dima's response makes more sense to me. My function pretty much loops back and forth because of the conditions I have currently set which I made with the boundary cases in mind.

Comment: Dima's response is the same as mine... But maybe I'm not totally clear... Explain? In any case, it's not a bad response so don't downvote it...

Comment: And I'm certain you don't try my solution before downvoting it.

Comment: Sorry but I'm sad when peoples downvote without commenting because it's totally useless. Just haters. To return on the subject: what happens if you try my solution. Curiosity is bad I know. :)

Comment: I am the one who downvoted. The answer is unclear, and the advice in the end is wrong.

Comment: This answer is similar to your first comment. You don't agree with that ? It's not unclear, it's not detailled. Can you explain please ? Thank you for your comment. :)